# How do I only let a certain username views messages on my website in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a model under:

```
rails generate model user name email password_digest
```

My UsersController allows a username to be created:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.new(user_params)
    if user.save
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to '/'
    else
      redirect_to '/signup'
    end
  end

private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

I can allow any user that is logged in to view a message but I was wondering how to specify which users.  How can I make a name called "Admin" only be able to view the message?

```
<% if current_user %>
  Signed in as <%= current_user.name %> | <%= link_to "Logout", '/logout' %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to 'Login', '/login' %> | <%= link_to 'Signup', '/signup' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: this question has a couple unknowns, and you will need to think about what you want the feature to work.  Is it only the user and an admin type role that will be able to view the messages. Or is there going to be a way for the user to give a set of other users the ability to see this message (either explicit, or part of say some shared group, etc...?)  These have different solutions.  You should be looking into authorization systems (you have the authentication, part already). Authorization systems(I like `Pundit`) will allow you to control who can see, modify, delete what exactly.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check into Pundit.  It started out as me really just wanting to be  the only user to edit information for a personal app.  But I think I will expand it just for learning purposes.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1: (If you are looking to extend the project )**

- You can use [**`Devise`**](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and add a new admin role and make the user admin

**Solution 2: (Easy to go)**

- If you don't want to handle roles just add a boolean field `admin` and you will get `admin?` method on `User` instance

  ```
  <% if current_user && current_user.admin? %>
  ```

  1. Add a boolean field

     ```
     rails g migration AddAdminToUsers admin:boolean
     ```
  2. Add default value of admin field to `false`

     ```
     class AddAdminToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
       def change
         add_column :users, :admin, :boolean, default: false
       end
     end
     ```
  3. Create first admin user through `rails console`, `script` or `seed`

     ```
     User.create(
       name: 'Admin User Name', 
       email: 'admin@example.com', 
       password: 'password', 
       admin: true)
     ```
  4. Now you can check if the user is admin or not using `admin?` method

     ```
     @user = User.find(1)
     @user.admin?
     #=> true
     ```

Comment: So if I go with Solution 2 and set up an admin boolean, how do I go about creating an admin account?  Do I just go through the standard Create User form and use admin as the name?

Comment: You can set first admin from console and then let only admins change this value. It is easies solution.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new.  Could you give me an example of this?  I'm thinking...                                                                                                       AdminUser.create!(:name => 'namehere', :email => 'admin@example.com', :password => 'password', :password_confirmation => 'password'

Answer (score 0):

Name is not good idea, better make boolean `:is_admin` in user and then you can do something like `if is_admin?` (like current_user).

```
<%= if current_user && current_user.is_admin? %>
```

Also you can use roles.